# How to extract numeric values from a structure object in R

Tags: r, structure, numeric, names

I need to extract numeric values from a variable which is a structure combined with numeric values and names

```
structure(c(-1.14332132657709, -1.1433213265771, -1.20580568266868, 
-1.75735158849487, -1.35614113300058), .Names = c("carbon", 
"nanotubes", "potential", "neuron", "cell", "adhesion"))
```

At the end I would like to have a vector with just this information

```
c(-1.14332132657709, -1.1433213265771, -1.20580568266868, 
-1.75735158849487, -1.35614113300058)
```

how can I do it?
many thanks

Comment: dimnames and vector of numeric values are not the same length

Comment: Is there one `.Name` too many? Otherwise `as.numeric()`

Comment: I'm not sure what you wanna do. If you just want to get rid of names then why not just doing `as.numeric(x)` or `names(x) <- NULL`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both `as.numeric()` and `unname()` do this:

```
R> structure(c(-1.14332132657709, -1.1433213265771, -1.20580568266868,
+              -1.75735158849487, -1.35614113300058, NA),
+            .Names = c("carbon", "nanotubes", "potential", 
+            "neuron", "cell", "adhesion"))
   carbon nanotubes potential    neuron      cell  adhesion 
 -1.14332  -1.14332  -1.20581  -1.75735  -1.35614        NA 
R> foo
   carbon nanotubes potential    neuron      cell  adhesion 
 -1.14332  -1.14332  -1.20581  -1.75735  -1.35614        NA 
R>
R> as.numeric(foo)            ## still my 'default' approach
[1] -1.14332 -1.14332 -1.20581 -1.75735 -1.35614       NA
R>
R> unname(foo)                ## maybe preferable though
[1] -1.14332 -1.14332 -1.20581 -1.75735 -1.35614       NA
R>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
myVec <- structure(c(-1.14332132657709, -1.1433213265771, -1.20580568266868, 
  -1.75735158849487, -1.35614113300058), .Names = c("carbon", 
  "nanotubes", "potential", "neuron", "cell"))

as.numeric(myVec)
# [1] -1.143321 -1.143321 -1.205806 -1.757352 -1.356141
```

Or

```
names(myVec) <- NULL
```

**EDIT:**

`unname` for an atomic vector is just `names(obj) <- NULL` with some superfluous code.

Comment: @ClaudioMeo, just added an explanation as to why I hold `names(myVec) <- NULL` to be more direct than using `unname`

Answer (score 2):

What about `unname`?

```
> myVec <- structure(c(-1.14332132657709, -1.1433213265771, -1.20580568266868, 
  -1.75735158849487, -1.35614113300058), .Names = c("carbon", 
  "nanotubes", "potential", "neuron", "cell"))

+ + > > unname(myVec)
[1] -1.143321 -1.143321 -1.205806 -1.757352 -1.356141
```